# ASP.NET MVC HttpPost posting null model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Form posts from webpage `MakeBooking` to `FinalBooking` to ascertain certain information such as number of guests, so the `FinalBooking` page can give you enough textboxes to input guest information for all guests required.

When in debug mode, both models in `MakeBooking` post are populated. After post, in `FinalBooking`, model is null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MakeBooking(BookingModel model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("FinalBooking", "Booking", new { model = model });
    }

    public ActionResult FinalBooking(BookingModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: model is null in FinalBooking or MakeBooking to?

Comment: Could you share the relevant portion of your view, too?

Comment: You need to check the model state before assuming the post was correct. Check `ModelState.IsValid` and if false, return the model back to the view and it will display any validation errors in the validation section. There is also an errors collection you can parse for diagnostic information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass a model with `RedirectToAction` like that. you need to use either **TempData** or **Session** to transfer the model object between your calls.

`RedirectToAction` method returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action.

The below example shows how to transfer data using TempData.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MakeBooking(BookingModel model)
{
    TempData["TempBookingModel"]=model;
    return RedirectToAction("FinalBooking", "Booking");
}

public ActionResult FinalBooking()
{       
    var model= TempData["TempBookingModel"] as BookingModel; 
    return View(model);
}
```

Internally `TempData` is using Session as the storage mechanism.

Comment: Exactly. Redirect To Action is going to issue an http redirect code to the client (302 I think) and the new action will be invoked. This means the values set in the third param are **route** values.

Answer (score 2):

It should work

```
return RedirectToAction("FinalBooking", "Booking", model);
```

Comment: Would rep this if I could, used it elsewhere in project now :)